# Remove all whitespace from C# string with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am building a string of last names separated by hyphens. Sometimes a whitespace gets caught in there. I need to remove all whitespace from end result.

Sample string to work on:

> Anderson -Reed-Smith

It needs to end up as (no space after Anderson):

> Anderson-Reed-Smith

The last name string is in a string variable, LastName.

I am using a regular expression:

```
Regex.Replace(LastName, @"[\s+]", "");
```

The result of this is:

> Anderson -Reed-Smith.

I also tried:

```
Regex.Replace(LastName, @"\s+", "");
```

and

```
Regex.Replace(LastName, @"\s", "");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need regex if the name is the only data in the string. Otherwise you can probably use ( -|- | - )

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Instead of a `RegEx` use `Replace` for something that simple:

```
LastName = LastName.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

Comment: This. I would vote this answer up right now, but I've reached my voting limit for today.

Comment: Didn't know there was a limit!

Comment: But not with tabs or other whitespace characters other than space (ordinal 32).

Comment: @maxwellb - From the OP, it looks like they are only dealing with "spaces"

Comment: Not sure what the deal was, I tried the above and it still didn't work, then I removed an earlier call to .Trim, then it started working. I guess it didnt like looking at the same thing twice.  Either way, I am good to go now.

Comment: @maxwellb So what is your suggestion on this?

Answer (score 69):

`Regex.Replace` does not modify its first argument (recall that strings are immutable in .NET) so the call

```
Regex.Replace(LastName, @"\s+", "");
```

leaves the `LastName` string unchanged. You need to call it like this:

```
LastName = Regex.Replace(LastName, @"\s+", "");
```

All three of your regular expressions would have worked. However, the first regex would remove all plus characters as well, which I imagine would be unintentional.

Comment: This should be the correct answer to the original question.

Answer (score 14):

No need for regex. This will also remove tabs, newlines etc

```
var newstr = String.Join("",str.Where(c=>!char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

**WhiteSpace chars :** `0009 , 000a , 000b , 000c , 000d , 0020 , 0085 , 00a0 , 1680 , 180e , 2000 , 2001 , 2002 , 2003 , 2004 , 2005 , 2006 , 2007 , 2008 , 2009 , 200a , 2028 , 2029 , 202f , 205f , 3000`.

Comment: Have a problem. Want to solve it with regex. Now I have two problems. Solve it with LINQ. Still two problems :-)

Comment: @JuliánUrbano Yes Regex can be a problematic while maintaining, but I can't say the same for Linq.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano, you should never *want* to solve anything because it is a particular API.  Far too many questions are answered on this site with a LINQ answer, even though - in essence - it can be solved far more easily and far quicker.  Pick the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest and general way to do this (line terminators, tabs will be processed as well). Regex powerful facilities don't really needed to solve this problem, but Regex can decrease performance.

```
                       new string
                           (stringToRemoveWhiteSpaces
                                .Where
                                (
                                    c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)
                                )
                                .ToArray<char>()
                           )
```

OR

```
                       new string
                           (stringToReplaceWhiteSpacesWithSpace
                                .Select
                                (
                                    c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ? ' ' : c
                                )
                                .ToArray<char>()
                           )
```

Comment: FYI, I did a benchmark test between the first code snipped here (stringToRemoveWhiteSpaces) and the String.Join code posted by I4V and you new String(stringToRemoveWhiteSpaces...) code ran about 40% faster.

Comment: @JerrenSaunders But what about compared with the Regex solution? :-D

Comment: I can't say I tested the regex solution.  I tend to agree with CSharpCoder's comments in this answer that the overhead of regex can sometimes be too much for the more simple task.  That said, to be fair I should not make that assumption without including it in a benchmark.

Comment: The benchmark results when performing each operation 10M times: The first snippet here (.Where): 10813 ticks, I4V's Join/Where: 13140 ticks, dasblinkenlight's Regex.Replace: 22969 ticks, and Gabe's accepted answer's: 1297 ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Using REGEX you can remove the spaces in a string.

The following namespace is mandatory.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Syntax:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"\s", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write so, for exaple with phone number:

```
private static string GetFormattedPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    => string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber) ? string.Empty 
    : Regex.Replace(phoneNumber, @"[+,\-,\(,\), \s+]*", string.Empty);

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(GetFormattedPhoneNumber("+375 (24) 55-333 "));
    }
/*
    Output: 3752455333
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have you remove whitespaces:

```
   var year = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(space, @"&nbsp;", string.Empty).Replace("Year: ", string.Empty).Trim();
```

Answer (score -2):

Below is the code that would replace the white space from the file name into given URL and also we can remove the same by using string.empty instead of "~"

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
          {
           string origFileName = Path.GetFileName(url);
           string modiFileName = origFileName.Trim().Replace(" ", "~");
           url = url.Replace(origFileName , modiFileName );
          }
          return url;
```

Comment: Op said _" I need to remove all **whitespace**"_ and used `\s`. But this handle only `" "` space and is mostly not related. While `Trim()` handles only leading and trailling space. I don't see fit.

Answer (score -3):

Why use Regex when you can simply use the Trim() method

```
Text='<%# Eval("FieldDescription").ToString().Trim() %>'
```

OR

```
string test = "Testing    ";
test.Trim();
```

Comment: He requires removing all spaces not just leading and ending spaces