# C# Application crash with code CLR20r3... Because of Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, assemblies

I am facing a pretty weird issue, and I can't understand even after hours of research, so that's why I am sharing this problem.

I created a little Windows Form which is working perfectly on my computer, both with a Debug version and a release version. Everything was pretty nice, until I tried to launch it on the computer which is supposed to *really* use it. I got the famous **CLR20r3** error, so I search on Internet and saw various possible causes :

- References used by the software might not be on the computer which is running the software, so I added all the references as local copies.
- It could be a .NET issue, so I uninstall and re-installed it.
- It might be some specific CPU weird standard, so I tried to deploy it for *x86* only.

But none of those solutions worked. After hours and hours of trials, compilations and reseaches, I found the cause : I have this specific part in my code, which is supposed to remove any extra-spaces from logs strings :

```
for(int i = 0; i < lastlogs.Length; i++)
{
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
    Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
    lastlogs[i] = regex.Replace(lastlogs[i], " ");
}
```

If I comment out this part, the code is running perfectly. I added a reference to `System.Text.RegularExpressions`, but I can't see it in the assemblies list, so I suppose it is some kind of build-in Windows assembly. But if that's the case, it's strange that the software crashes because it can't find it...

I would like to understand why this crash is happening, and if anyone have a possible way to solve this problem.

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions is part of System.DLL.  See the documentation for the Regex class.

Comment: I take it there's an exception being thrown when calling the regex.Replace? What are the exception details?

Comment: Thanks @Amy for your answer, but it seems that System.DLL can't be added as a local copy neither. That's why I find it's a strange behaviour.

Comment: System.DLL is in the GAC.  There's no reason to add it as a local copy.

Comment: @RussellTroywest When I run this with my developement PC, there is absolutely no exception. Since the test PC doesn't have Visual Studio on it, I can't really test that, but the only exception I can see is this CLR20r3

Comment: Of course you can see the exception.  Use a try/catch block, and log the exception.  Also log the variables in use at the time of the exception, such as `i` and `lastLogs[i]`, so you can know the conditions under which the exception was thrown.

Comment: You might be able to get the details from the event viewer on the machine that the software is failing on.

Comment: I'm going to guess that that at some point lastLogs[i] is null and replace is throwing an ArgumentNullException. You need to get the exception details though and work out what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all whitespace from C# string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346146/remove-all-whitespace-from-c-sharp-string-with-regex)

Comment: @RussellTroywest thanks a lot that was exactly the case, I forgot to check for null entries, which was raising the Argument.NullException. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DennisChristian If you have read the question you obviously saw that the issue is absolutely not about removing whitespaces with regex but about a compiled programm error.

Comment: FYI a CLR20r3 error is usually code related. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4052770/3740093