# Dealing with Empty cells from Excel export

Tags: asp.net, excel, export, isnullorempty

I have an export function in my asp.net application. I want to remove all the white spaces/nulls in the list. Any way to trim it?

This is how my code looks like:

My GetData methode from the Database:

```
          public void GetData()
       {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GS1connectionString"].ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DAtabase.dbo.SP_EXPORT", connection)) //Extract data: no cons first and cons after
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                {
                    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Session["TaskTable"] = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('No data found, try again');", true);
        }
    }
```

Clean dataTable methode:

```
    public DataTable removeEmptyColumns(DataTable table)
    {
        int k = 0, l = 0;
        DataTable dtResult = table.Clone();
        DataRow row = dtResult.NewRow();
        row = dtResult.NewRow();
        for (k = 0; k < table.Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < table.Rows.Count; l++)
            {
                if (k == l)
                    row[k] = table.Rows[k][l];
            }
        }
        dtResult.Rows.Add(row);
        dtResult.AcceptChanges();
        return dtResult;
    }
```

The Export to excel button:

```
    protected void Button_Export_DS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
        DataTable dat = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
        dat = (DataTable)Session["TaskTable"];
        dtNew = removeEmptyColumns(dat);
        //Export to excel from datatable stored in a session


            if (dtNew.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                int i = 1;
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet" + i++);
                    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtNew, true);
                    worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

                    Response.Clear();
                    package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachchment; filename=DS_Export.xls");
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                    Response.End();
                }
            }

    }
```

I have an export function in my asp.net application. I want to remove all the white spaces/nulls in the list. Any way to trim it?

Comment: this might help https://forums.asp.net/t/2006863.aspx?How+to+remove+empty+null+rows+from+data+table

Comment: Hi Maddy, thanks for response. Can you please tell me how to apply the example from your link into my code?

Comment: Have you looked at Regex.Replace? You will find good example in:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346146/remove-all-whitespace-from-c-sharp-string-with-regex

Comment: Hi @SeyedMortezaMousavi your example looks interesting, the question is how I apply it to the code above? Mayve you can set an example

Comment: Your datatable is having the null values and empty spaces in the columns??

Answer (score 0):

You copy and paste this function:

```
public DataTable removeEmptyColumns(DataTable table)
{
    int k = 0, l = 0;
    DataTable dtResult = table.Clone();
    DataRow row = dtResult.NewRow();
    row = dtResult.NewRow();
    for (k = 0; k < table.Rows.Count ; k++)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < table.Rows.Count; l++)
        {
            if (k == l)
                row[k] = table.Rows[k][l];
        }
    }
    dtResult.Rows.Add(row);
    dtResult.AcceptChanges();
    return dtResult;
}
```

And then use the function like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)Session["TaskTable"];
dtNew = removeEmptyColumns(dt);
```

After that, use this dtNew in this:

```
if (dtNew.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    int i = 1;
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet" + i++);
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtNew, true);
        worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

        Response.Clear();
        package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachchment; filename=Export.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi 
I just did like you suggested and I'm getting an error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column 5.
It's related to: {
                     if (k == l)
                        row[k] = table.Rows[k][l];
              }

Comment: Can you please post your sample datatable, so that I can give more suggestion on that

Comment: I just updated my answer above, you can see the whole code

Comment: 5 columns
and thousands of rows, data will keep populating into the database on daily basis, so it's dynamic

Comment: Number of rows can extend too eventually